How to execute specific code before each project in Playwright
I'm trying to separate my tests using project, when each project executes tests of a permission-level.
Each permission-level project has it's own setup & tear-down projects that sets-up the environment for that permission-level.
Each project must be executed only after it's setup project has run.
The problem is that according to Playwright docs about running-sequence:

If there are more than one dependency then these project dependencies
will be run first and in parallel.
So, when I'm executing npx playwright test all of the setup projects executing, and only after they have all finished - the projects themselves being executed without their setup.

  projects: [
    // User
    {
      name: "user-level setup",
      testMatch: /userLevel\/global.setup\.ts/,
      teardown: "user-level cleanup",
    },
    {
      name: "user-level cleanup",
      testMatch: /userLevel\/global.teardown\.ts/,
    },
    {
      name: "user-level",
      testMatch: "userTests/*.spec.ts",
      dependencies: ["user-level setup"],
    },

    // Admin
    {
      name: "admin-level setup",
      testMatch: /adminLevel\/global.setup\.ts/,
      teardown: "admin-level cleanup",
    },
    {
      name: "admin-level cleanup",
      testMatch: /adminLevel\/global.teardown\.ts/,
    },
    {
      name: "admin-level",
      testMatch: "adminTests/*.spec.ts",
      dependencies: ["admin-level setup"],
    }
  ]

So, how can I avoid this situation?

Interesting problem.  I guess you could execute the user level tests first by passing the --project user-level on the command line and then do the same for the admin level tests after.
Or have a separate playwright config for the admin level stuff and pass --config playwright.adminlevel.config.ts on the command line.
But of course, you would end up with two sets of test results (which I think could be aggregated).

@AutomationAndy I did a quick test, and looks like only test results of projects from the same config file can be aggregated, so --config isn't a good solution for me, thanks for the comment though
